# Insert bulk data with INSERT statement built dynamically into a flow variable

Tags: dynamic, mule, bulkinsert

I'm new to database connector in Mule 3.7.3. I'm trying to insert bulk data using INSERT statement that formed dynamically. I don't know what do you guys usually call this approach, what I intend to do is, load multiple files into respective staging table dynamically, instead of having multiple choice routes and hard code the INSERT statement in each route.

My flowVars.insertStatement contains value like this: "INSERT INTO [roomService] ([RoomId],[ServiceId],[DateTime]) VALUES (#[payload.roomId],#[payload.serviceId],#[payload.dateTime])"

When I tried with these:

```
<db:insert config-ref="Staging_DB" doc:name="insert-data-into-staging-db" bulkMode="true">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.insertStatement]]]></db:parameterized-query>
```

This gives me "Query type must be one of '[INSERT, STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)"

```
<db:insert config-ref="Staging_DB" doc:name="insert-data-into-staging-db" bulkMode="true">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.insertStatement]]]></db:dynamic-query>
```

This gives me "Bulk query cannot contain a parameterized SQL query (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)"

```
<db:insert config-ref="Staging_DB" doc:name="insert-data-into-staging-db" bulkMode="true">
    <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.insertStatement]]]></db:dynamic-query>
```

This gives me "Index: 0 (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException)"

I need some pointers how to do this correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you wont be able to use bulk mode with your approach.

you probably defined `flowVars.insertStatement` like this:

```
<set-variable variableName="insertStatement" value="&quot;INSERT INTO [roomService] ([RoomId],[ServiceId],[DateTime]) VALUES (#[payload.roomId],#[payload.serviceId],#[payload.dateTime])&quot;" doc:name="set insertStatement"/>
```

this will make sure `payload.roomId`and other flowVars wont become `null` after defining the variable, but at the same time they wont be replaced by the `db:insert` component either.

following configuration uses the `foreach` component instead of bulk mode, but will work for your:

```
<set-payload doc:name="test data" value="#[[{ &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Chevon&quot; }, { &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Yevgeniy&quot; }]]"/>
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
    <set-variable variableName="sql" value="insert into TEST(name) values ('#[payload.name]')" doc:name="set sql variable"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="INSERT">
        <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.sql]]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:insert>
</foreach>
```

Comment: Hi @Yevgeniy, thanks for taking time to respond. The problem is I have to get the VALUES string (VALUES (#[payload.roomId],#[payload.serviceId],#[payload.dateTime])) from a property file into a flow variable and then concatenate it into the flowVars.insertStatement. If I specifically mention the payload field that I want to insert data into, then it's not dynamic. Let me know if you have any better idea of doing this.

Comment: sorry, then i just do not understand the problem :(